# what do you call a civilized person?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

what do you call a civilized person?

Civilian doesn't count, since a soldier can be civilized as well. I need one word to describe a person that is civilized, but not necessarily a civilian. It needs to be a name as well, and not an adjective, like "refined".

Comment: A gentleman or a cosmopolite, probably.

Comment: It would be good if you read [the guidelines](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for [tag:single-word-requests], as that might help you to improve your question.

Comment: When you say "civilized", you mean someone who is part of a civilization?  Or do you mean someone who uses good manners (as opposed to a savage)?

Comment: I'd say "rare".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a [citizen:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Citizen)

> - a native or naturalized member of a state or other political community
> - a native or naturalized member of a state or nation who owes allegiance to its government and is entitled to its protection.

(from TFD)

[World citizen](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_citizenship):

> - In broad usage, the term global citizenship or world citizenship typically defines a person who places their identity with a "global community" above their identity as a citizen of a particular nation or place. The idea is that one’s identity transcends geography or political borders and that the planetary human community is interdependent and whole; humankind is essentially one. The term has use in education and political philosophy and has enjoyed popular use in social movements such as the "World Citizen" movement and the Mondialisation movement.

(from Wikipedia)

Comment: Many of us in the UK prefer to think of ourselves as loyal subjects, rather than citizens!

Comment: And many of us are happy with our legal designation of *citizen*, having regard to British Nationality Act of 1981. 'The category of British subjects now includes only those people formerly known as *British subjects without citizenship* and people born in Ireland before 1949.'

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial AmE there is the admonition, "Why don't you act like a human being?" which implies civilized behavior - or the shorter, "C'mon, be human" which means the same thing.

In the NE US, we often say "He/She is 'good people'" (using the plural for a single person) to mean someone who is thoughtful, friendly, down-to-earth, and/or generous. We also borrow the Yiddish expression *mensch* (literally, 'person') but used in the same way.